Does epistemology categorize knowledge into 5 categories, like Justice Peter Gibson did?
Is Justice Peter Gibson partaking in epistemology below? He graduated in 1955 from Oxford in Literae Humaniores that offers philosophy, before he became a justice. But he's not a professional philosopher, thus  I would like expert opinions on his scale of knowledge. thanks!

15.36 In Baden v Société Générale (1992), Peter Gibson J distinguished five categories of knowledge
(at 250):

(i) actual knowledge;
(ii) wilfully shutting one’s eyes to the obvious;
(iii) wilfully and recklessly
failing to make such inquiries as an honest and reasonable man would make;
(iv)
knowledge of circumstances which would indicate the facts to an honest and reasonable man;
(v) knowledge of circumstances which would put an honest and reasonable man
on inquiry.


Penner, James. Law of Trusts. 2022, 12th edn, page 396.

Epistemology is a vast enterprise, each philosopher has her own, so there is no "it" to categorize things authoritatively. Gibson's list seems like a reasonable breakdown for the purposes of adjudicating claims where the state of person's knowledge affects the severity of the offense, etc., but it is not something most philosophers would find epistemologically salient. It is more about practical and psychological aspects of knowing than knowledge as such. For epistemological classifications of knowledge as used in philosophy, see IEP, Kinds of Knowledge.

(ii) and (iii) don't seem like categories of knowledge.  So, perhaps the title of your question is misleading.  Further epistemology is a portion of philosophy with many, many philosophers and for that matter non-philosophers, all with their own approaches and opinions.

You ask:

Is Justice Peter Gibson partaking in epistemology below?

Yes, but as Conifold notes in comments, the epistemological taxonomy that Gibson provides is within the practice of the philosophy of law, and is therefore an approach that deviates significantly from mainstream thinking of professional epistemologists. What one has to recognize is that every profession that has an approach to epistemology will answer the question "What is knowledge, and what types are there?" differently. For instance, Robert Audi's Epistemology (GB) is greatly preoccupied in the opening of his book not with a taxonomy interested in assessing an agent's willingness to know, but a taxonomy of general sources of knowledge: perception, memory, consciousness, reason, and testimony.
Epistemological theories, therefore, tend to be complicated theses that do not easily reduce to summary descriptions and taxonomies, and therefore like novels have an undeniably personal character to them. Part of what makes an epistemological theory unique is the particular interests or intersectionality that a philosopher has with other topics. How does epistemology intersect with ontology? What sort of methods does epistemology have? What is the role of epistemological thinking in metaphysics? How can knowledge be managed in a business setting? What about historical methods is epistemological in character? Is there a common epistemological perspective among pre-Scoratics? So on and so forth.

In European philosophy the first and seminal classification of knowledge has been compiled by Aristotle in the beginning of his Metaphysics, Book 1 (980 a 21-981 b 13).
Aristotle inspects the whole path of developing “knowledge” by non-human animals and humans along the key steps

power of sensation,
power of memory,
experience,
science,
art,
wisdom.

Aristotle considers knowing the "reasons" of the things an indicator of the highest form of knowledge.
